# how to set a custom block in all pages?

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

I am new to magento. I created a block to place this block in all pages, but this is showing double time in home page.

below is my code

//local.xml

</block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_catagory_default>
-->

```
<page_one_column translate="label">
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>

<page_empty translate="label">
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</page_empty>

<page_three_columns translate="label">
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</page_three_columns >

<page_two_columns_left translate="label" >
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left>
```

and //catalog.xml

```
<reference name="left">
            <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
          <block name="mtb.template" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

my block is

[image]

can any one tell me where i went wrong?

if my block show in all pages what I can do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add this to only one of your layout files.

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block name="mtb.template.left" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block name="mtb.template.right" type="core/template" template="page/mtb/mytemplate.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

<strike>But in case you have a page with the layout `3columns` the block will appear bot on the left and right column. For that you need to remove one of them. You can do it like this.</strike>

```
<page_three_columns translate="label">
    <remove name="mtb.template.right" /><!-- or "mtb.template.left"-->
</page_three_columns>
```

To remove it from a page do this:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <remove name="mtb.template.right" /><!-- or "mtb.template.left"-->
</catalog_category_view>
```

Comment: hi marius, now not displaying duplicates in home page, but in products view page displaying duplicates even though i wrote the  <catalog_catagory_default translate="label">
        <remove name="mtb.template.right"></remove>
    </catalog_catagory_default> the url is http://localhost/magento/index.php/apparel/shoes.html Can you tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: You mean is duplicated on the same side? or one on the left and one on the right?

Comment: yes, but not in home page. showing another page(catalog)

Comment: "Yes" what? You get one on the left and one on the right? Or both on the left?

Comment: yes, I get one on the left and one on the right.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I've tested and it worked for me.